# Automatizando o deploy utilizando o MSBuild

Tags: cmd, powershell

Estou criando um bat para compilar e publicar um projeto do Visual Studio utilizando o `MSBuild`.

No entanto, preciso informar um usuário e senha para o `MSBuild`. O que estou fazendo, é solitar no bat o usuário e senha. Porém, não gostaria de ver a senha ao digitar no cmd. Basicamente seria como já é o `net use` que quando necessário ele solicita o usuário e senha.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
@echo off
set /p username="UserName: "
set /p password="Password: "
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe Syns.sln /p:Configuration=Produção;DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=prod.pubxml /MaxCpuCount:8 /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True /p:UserName=%username% /p:Password=%password%
```

Seguindo a resposta do @rray eu reescrevi o script usando powershell, agora consigo pegar a senha de uma forma mais segura

```
Write-Host "UserName:"
$username = Read-Host

Write-Host "Password:"
$password = Read-Host -AsSecureString
$password = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($password))


$msbuild = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe"
$collectionOfArgs = @("D:\Projetos\Syns\Syns\Syns.sln", 
                      "/p:Configuration=Prod;DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=prod.pubxml", 
                      "/MaxCpuCount:8", 
                      "/p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True", 
                      "/p:UserName=$username", 
                      "/p:Password=$password")

& $msbuild $collectionOfArgs
```

Comment: Pode usar powershell?

Comment: Posso, só teria que reescrever usando o powershell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma alternativa com o powershell é na hora de solicitar o valor de entrada adicionar o argumento `-AsSecureString`. Ao testar testar no ISE vai abrir uma caixa de entrada mas ao como script os caracteres serão trocados por astericos.

```
Write-Host "Informe sua senha:"
$senhaCodificada = Read-Host -AsSecureString
$senhaTextoPuro = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($senhaCodificada))
```

**Baseado em:**

[Powershell SecureString Encrypt/Decrypt To Plain Text Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21744179/1342547)

[How can I use powershell's read-host function to accept a password for an external service?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15007104/1342547)

Comment: Vou testar aqui

Comment: Com o powershell, como ficaria a chamada ao MSBuild?

Comment: @PabloTondolodeVargas https://stackoverflow.com/a/871605

Comment: Eu editei a minha pergunta com a suas sugestões, consegui chamar o MSBuild, só a senha não está indo corretamente.

Comment: Achei meu erro e a solução, valeu